# How do i plot a pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar() with this weird columns in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I currently have this dataframe that look like this:

[image]

Currently, i'm trying to plot a barplot that is grouped in such a way:

- For each respective year_of_assessment, i want to plot the return_type, which shall be represented in 3 distinctive colors. And each year_of_assessment will be shown in the bar

However, i've tried to plot out the barchart and i ended out in this result:
[image]

Below is the code that i've tried to use to plot the bar plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# import the csv file
dataname = 'Datasets\\filing-of-tax-returns-for-individual-income-tax-and-corporate-income-tax.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(dataname,na_values=['na'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# drop the NaN values
df2 = df.dropna()

# drop the rows that include values for individual income tax as it is irrelevent
df2 = df2[df2.tax_type != 'Individual Income Tax']
df2

# drop the column tax_type as we alr filter out to be a corporate income tax
df3 = df2.drop(columns = 'tax_type')
df3

# draw the bar chart to see the respectiive return_type for each respective year
df3.plot.bar(x='year_of_assessment',rot=0,figsize=(40,20))
plt.show()
```

***Disclaimer: I was told not to use matplotlib to plot out the graph.***

Comment: maybe this help: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html

Comment: Check this: https://kanoki.org/2019/09/16/dataframe-visualization-with-pandas-plot/

Comment: It's funny since every plotting library is built on top of matplotlib. The easiest way I can think of is Seaborn's [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html): `seaborn.catplot(kind='bar', data=df3, x='year_of_assessment', y='no_of_return', hue='return_type')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot this chart using Pandas' `plot()` by simply rearranging the data *inside Pandas* before you plot.

Simply pivot your data, so that the years of assessment becomes the index and the return types become the columns.

You can do that with the simple operation:

```
df4 = df3.pivot_table(
    index=['year_of_assessment'], 
    columns=['return_type'],
)
```

At this point, a simple `df4.plot.bar()` will do what you want.

You can make it slightly nicer by adjusting the labels of the axis, legend and title, but it's mostly cosmetic adjustments at this point:

```
ax = df4.plot.bar()
ax.legend(labels=df4.columns.levels[1])
ax.set_xlabel('Year of Assessment')
ax.set_title('Returns Received On Time')
plt.show()
```

Here's a sample plot I got with a small sample of data that looks like the one you've shared:

[image: Plot Sample]